# Option Values for insert

Tags: php, html-select

Right now i have this:

```
     <option>Family</option>
     <option>Friend</option>
```

If i wanted friend to have a value of "3423432424", how can i do that while still displaying Friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the tag value on the `option` element.. Or maybe I misunderstood your problem...

```
 <option value="3423432424">Friend</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<option value="3423432424">Friend</option>
```

More information can be found on the [`<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/option) element.

```
<select name="category">
  <option>Family</option>
  <option value="3423432424" selected="selected">Friend</option>
  <!-- ... -->
</select>
```

Would result in:

```
<?php
  echo $_REQUEST['category']; // outputs: 3423432424
?>
```

(Assuming it was submitted with a form, and I use `$_REQUEST` to denote that it can be either a POST/GET value)